# jRecorder throwing Uncaught TypeError: getFlashMovie(...).jSendFileToServer is not a function

Tags: javascript, jrecorder

I'm working with `jRecorder`.
It was working so fine but suddenly starts throwing

```
TypeError:  getFlashMovie(...).jSendFileToServer is not a function
```

Here is the [link](http://107.170.69.49/cloudtutor/sound/upload/test_sound), you can see the error in console after recording and then click Upload your recording.

Comment: Issue Resolved, What I was doing wrong was z-index of #flasharea, I played with id flasharea which contains the adobe flash setting popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Resolved, What I was doing wrong was z-index of #flasharea, I played with id flasharea which contains the adobe flash setting popup.